# subsetting nonconsecituve observations in R

Tags: r

I have a table with >2M rows. I am only interested in percentiles of one variable vs. percentiles of number of observations (e.g. Lorentz curve).

- How do I create a smaller dataframe that contains e.g. observations number 1,101,201,301,...,last , or observations that corresponds to e.g. the 1,2,3,...,100 percentile of total number of observations?
- Is there a quick way to get the lorenz curve of (index, variable) with axes on a percentage basis? Right now I was thinking of adding variables for percentiles of index and variables and then plot them against each other.

Thanks,

Roberto

Comment: this package may help you
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ineq

Answer (score 1):

As for the first question, I would use the `quantile` function, to get a subset of the dataframe according to the 1,2,3,...,100 percentile of the total number of (say) first column's observations (assuming integer values in column 1)

```
df[df[,1] %in% round(quantile(df[,1], probs = c(1:100)/100)),]
```

Comment: I agree that this is something that Roberto asked for, but I'm not sure it's a useful subset, since it could have very different properties to the original.  There could be several rows that match some percentiles, and none matching others.

Comment: George, I tried the following (I am interested in quantiles of row numbers):


`df_small <- subset(df, row(df) %in% round(nrow(df)/100*(1:100),0))`

I get: `Error: (subscript) logical subscript too long` and I can't figure out why this is. Ideas?

Richie: your observation is right but I just want a summary Pareto plot with 100 datapoints, so this should be fine.

Comment: @Roberto I would suggest `df_small <- df[round(nrow(df)/100*(1:100),0),]`

Answer (score 1):

For a 'big' dataset

```
dfr <- data.frame(x = 1:1000, y = runif(1000))
```

You can take subsets of regularly spaced rows with

```
dfr[!(seq_len(nrow(dfr)) %% 50),]
```

Or random subsets with

```
dfr[sample(nrow(dfr), 20),]
```

As gd047 mentioned, use `quantile` to get quantiles/percentiles.